# Validate Java Preferences object against XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, preferences

Is there a way of validating a [preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) object against a [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C))? As the [preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) file uses as base an XML file in my opinion it should be possible to do this. Any advice on the topic would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an official XSD version of Java [preferences.dtd](http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd), but it's easy enough to create one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="preferences">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="root">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="map"/>
              <xs:element name="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                  <xs:enumeration value="system"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="user"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="EXTERNAL_XML_VERSION" default="0.0"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="map">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="key" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="node">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="map"/>
        <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I hope that I don't misunderstand something, but on the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) of the Preferences class there is part pointing to http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd . That will be still enough. Accessing the given link would download the given DTD.

Comment: Perhaps it is I who misunderstood your question.  I thought that to validate preferences XML, you didn't want to use *DTD* (which *is* available) but instead *XSD* (which was *not* available).

Comment: I will edit the question as it seems that it's not clear what I need :(. So I need a way that a given preference file has the needed format. So what I need to make sure: a given property has just a given format of property let's say just a given value. The properties have just given names. etc